# Nginx remove trailing slash but not if query string is present

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule in Nginx to remove trailing slashes.

My rule so far is:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1;
```

I want to remove trailing slashes for all URL:s except those that has a query string directly after a trailing slash, how do you do that? I mean URLs that look like https://www.domain.tld/page/?query=xxx

Answer (score 0):

When using `rewrite`, the query string is appended automatically

From http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule:

> If in the line of replacement arguments are indicated, then the rest of the request arguments are appended to them. To avoid having them appended, place a question mark as the last character:

Just an FYI if you are using `rewrite` for a redirect it is [not recommended](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites) but no one is going to stop you.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not solve my rewrite problem. I have URL:s that have query strings directly after the slash, i.e /?isAjax=true which i don't want to be wiped out, since that request won't work after the rewrite.

Comment: @degdev9 did you finally solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This rule removes trailing slash from url on both cases and worked fine for me; you can customize the the `if` logic by the way

```
location ~ (.*)/$ {
  if ($query_string) {
    return 301 $scheme://$host$1?$query_string;
  }
  return 301 $scheme://$host$1;
}
```